# How to use specific datas from a CSV file to a JavaScript chart?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, google-visualization

So I would like to use specific datas out of a huge CSV file in order to create several JS Charts with different datas (from the same CSV file).

I'm pretty new to JS, and just successfully created simple charts with raw datas using Google Charts and D3.

My CSV contains over 20 columns and I would like to only use 2 or 3 for each charts.
Here is what my CSV looks like:
 `Volume;N° d'e;Référence interne;Date d'envoi de l'e;mois & année;Etat de l'e;Date de l'état;Date de l'état;Provenance;Email de l'expéditeur;Nom de l'expéditeur;Prénom de l'expéditeur;Entreprise expéditrice;Groupe de l'expéditeur;Email du destinataire;Nom du destinataire;Prénom du destinataire;Type destinataire;Entreprise du destinataire;Notification SMS;Nombre de pièces-jointes;Poids des pièces-jointes;Produit;Nombre de relances;Satut notification SMS;Satut notification email;`

So my question is : How do I use a specific column from a csv ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far? show some code snippet.

Comment: This is basically a little chart I created but I am now stuck at the part where I got to select the columns I need since I have no idea how to do so.. https://jsfiddle.net/8bhrf6po/1/

Comment: Before asking question read it first. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) to [hide columns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_hideColumns)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @WhiteHat
I will try this out